# NetworkManager-wait-online.service Failed

Tags: networking, upgrade, virtualbox, network-manager

I'm running Ubuntu (actually Lubuntu) on a Windows host. I was upgrading from version 16 to 17.10 when I got a screen saying something about systemctl having a new version and do I want to keep the old version, view the difference, or go with the new version. I accidently continued I believe with the old version and now my VM won't boot properly.

I get the following services fail at startup:

- `gpu-manager.service`
- `lightdm.service`
- `NetworkManager-wait-online.service`
- `plymouth-start.service`

If I try to `ping 8.8.8.8`, I get "Network is Unreachable"

`$route -n` doesn't return any entries.

```
$sudo ip route add default My.Router.IP.Address
```

Error: Nexthop has invalid gateway.

The output of ifconfig:[image]